# Regex to find exactly the given String

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find a regex to match a given string pattern. The string is 
    "ABC OK: 123 XYZ OK: 789"
Any other string that contains : after those strings can be considered as not a match.
I tried the following regex but nothing seems to work:

```
"[ABC OK:][a-zA-Z_0-9\\s][XYZ OK:][a-zA-Z_0-9\\s]^:"
"ABC OK:[a-zA-Z_0-9\\s]XYZ OK:[a-zA-Z_0-9\\s]^:"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try [`s.matches("ABC OK:[\\w\\s]+XYZ OK:[\\w\\s]+")`](https://regex101.com/r/NIfePT/1) if you are just validating the string. If you need to extract specific values, you might want to use `"ABC OK:\\s*(\\w+)\\s+XYZ OK:\\s*(\\w+)\\s*"` with `Matcher#matches()` and then accessing `matcher.group(1)` and `matcher.group(2)`.

Comment: The `^` symbol outside of square brackets means the start of a regex. Also, can you be more specific about what you are trying to match? Will `^ABC OK: 123 XYZ OK: 789$` not be enough?

Comment: I am just validating the string and after removing the ^ and adding the + at the end does work for my need. Thanks Wiktor.

Answer (score 0):

`ABC OK: 123 XYZ OK: 789` is a valid regex that will find that string ;-)

In your first example, `"[ABC OK:][a-zA-Z_0-9\\s][XYZ OK:][a-zA-Z_0-9\\s]^:"`, there are few problems here:

- `[ABC OK:]` means: match single character, and it must be one of `'A', 'B', 'C', ' ', 'O', 'K',` or `':'`
- `[a-zA-Z_0-9\\s]` -- this also matches single character only. If you want multiple of those, use `+` after it: `[a-zA-Z_0-9\\s]+`
- `^:` -- not sure what you think this should do, but since it's not at the beginning of the regex, `^` doesn't have any special meaning, so it will only match `"^:"` string.